# List of all URI elements for a website

Tags: web-crawlers

Does anyone know a good way of getting a list of all the URI elements for a website? I plan on moving a website to a new CMS and would like to setup some 301 redirects for articles, images, css, and js files that will be moved to a new location.

I'm looking for somewhat of a "site sucker" application that creates a list of URI elements for a website, instead of downloading them.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) it will crawl your website and find all links. The report is in HTML but I think you will be able to extract the links with some kind of regexp.